# Windows 10 resolution option grey out

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution

My device config is falcon desktop, dell monitor. When I connect to my monitor, the resolution is really weird. Everything appears so big.

I tried to change the resolution but the options are grey-out, I cannot choose. i checked the display adapter there are Microsoft basic displayer adapter and NVIDIA GeForce 1070. both driver are up to date. And I tried to uninstall the Microsoft basic adapter and restart but it will reappear when i start. The resolution is still grey.

Does anyone know what i can do?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the greyed out resolution slider?

Comment: Did you have multiple monitor? please select the actual monitor to change its display settings. You can also try to roll back the driver.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it appeared as if Windows 10 did not recognise my monitor as it said the monitor was PNP.  My monitor is a ViewSonic VX2235WM.  I pulled out the power cord on the monitor and then reconnected it.  Windows 10 recognised the monitor which went back to normal (to how it was before the problem occurred) and allowed display settings to be altered.  -  Lou Feb 27/20 3:54pm